Why is metadata consuming large amount of storage and how to optimize it?
I'm using PySpark with Apache Iceberg on an HDFS-based data lake, and I'm encountering significant storage issues. My application ingests real-time data every second. After approximately 2 hours, I get an error indicating that storage is full. Upon investigating the HDFS folder (which stores both data and metadata), I noticed that Iceberg's metadata consumes a surprisingly large amount of storage compared to the actual data.

Here’s my Spark configuration:
CONF = (
    pyspark.SparkConf()
    .set("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-runtime-3.5_2.12:1.5.0")
    .set("spark.sql.extensions", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions")
    .set("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkSessionCatalog")
    .set("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog.type", "hive")
    .set("spark.sql.catalog.local", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog")
    .set("spark.sql.catalog.local.type", "hadoop")
    .set("spark.sql.catalog.local.warehouse", 'warehouse')
    .set("spark.sql.defaultCatalog", "local")
    .set("spark.driver.port", "7070")
    .set("spark.ui.port", "4040")
)

My table creation code:
def get_create_channel_data_table_query() -> str:
    return f"""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS local.db.{CHANNEL_DATA_TABLE} (
        uuid STRING,
        channel_set_channel_uuid STRING,
        data FLOAT,
        file_uri STRING,
        index_depth FLOAT,
        index_time BIGINT,
        creation TIMESTAMP,
        last_update TIMESTAMP
    )
    """

Inserting data into the table:
def insert_row_into_table(spark: SparkSession, schema: StructType, table_name: str, row: tuple):
    df = spark.createDataFrame([row], schema)
    df.writeTo(f"local.db.{table_name}").append()

Problem:
Iceberg's metadata grows rapidly and takes up a huge amount of space relative to the data. I’m unsure why metadata consumption is so high.
Question:
What causes metadata to consume so much space ? are there best practices or configurations I could apply to reduce metadata storage ?

My application ingests real-time data every second. I'm afraid iceberg is not the best choice for this kind of use-case.

I've got the right answer to my question from here on Reddit

Inserting one row at a time will cause single row based
snapshot/transaction being created. So if you are inserting thousands
or millions of rows, expect each to create a snapshot and also create
a parquet of few KBs with just one record in it. INSERT INTO table
VALUES syntax will cause all kind of issues including the one you
reported.
I will suggest the following:
Try creating a staging table/file/in-memory location where you can
store the intermediate rows before doing a BULK upload into Iceberg
table. This way there will be only one snapshot/transaction and also
the underline parquet file size will also be optimal like 256MB
standard. For example create a csv file to hold few thousands of
records in the staging area and then upload that csv file as bulk
upload to Iceberg since then it will be considered a single
snapshot/transaction, this will keep your metadata folder space small
in size.
If you want to continue with your existing approach than Iceberg
provide options to expires and delete snapshots. You might want to run
the expire command after few thousand records being inserted. This way
your metadata folder space will be under check.
My recommendation will be Option#1.


Expanding on my comment above, from Iceberg docs:

Each write to an Iceberg table creates a new snapshot, or version, of
a table. Snapshots can be used for time-travel queries, or the table
can be rolled back to any valid snapshot.

So I wouldn't be surprised that for a table that consists of a significant number of partitions/files, the total size of iceberg manifests will increase pretty fast especially if you do a write/commit every second.
You can follow the above doc to reduce the number of stored versions, and keep purging old metadata and removing orphan files.
But I still think Iceberg is not the right storage layer for streaming data at a per-second rate, and other storage mechanisms should be considered instead -- HBase, Kudu, Solr(?)...

In addition with the previous response, did you try to implement a files compaction ?
Example
spark.sql(f"CALL local.system.rewrite_data_files('db.{TABLE}')")

Use compaction techniques to consolidate small files, allow to reduce the metadata referencing.
Here some optimizations that can help you : https://bigdataboutique.com/blog/iceberg-table-maintenance-4-best-practices-e914ea

Any suggestions on how to use this technique ? Should I apply it during streaming, and how would I implement it ?

No I think you need to implement it an independant job (scheduled once a day or once a week) in order to avoid degrading the performance of your real-time jobs.

useful link : https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/maintenance/

Rewriting data files and then expiring snapshots significantly reduced the data size.
